# 2D (Maximum From Each Column)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

After trying a lot of times and thinking again and again.. It feels like a frustrated person.
I'm here to get some suggestions from you guys..

Actually I'm trying to find the maximum of each ROW and COLUMN.
So by using divide and conquer technique, I write two separate functions one for finding max of each row and store it to row vector that i used as an argument. Respectively for columns.

```
void maxValuesR(int a[][cols], int rv[], int row)
void maxValuesC(int a[][cols], int cv[], int row)
```

PROBLEM: The code is not even compile, I just don't understnd the errors.. 
Please Help..

I Really Need Your Help Here!

The code is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int rows = 2;     // Declared As Global Variable
const int cols = 3; // Declared As Global Variable

void getData(int arr[][cols], int rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Element: ";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

}

void printData(int a[][cols], int rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void print_single(int a[], int row)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << "\t";
    }
}

void maxValuesR(int a[][cols], int rv[], int row)
{   int foxi;
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        foxi = a[i][0];
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {

                if(foxi < a[i][j])
                {
                    foxi = a[i][j];
                }
            }
            rv[i] = foxi;
    }
}

void maxValuesC(int a[][cols], int cv[], int row)
{
    int maxi;
    for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        maxi = a[0][i];
            for(int j = 0; j < row; j++)
            {

                if(maxi > a[j][i])
                {
                    maxi = a[j][[i];// show error here => expected a '{' introducing lambda body
                }
            }
            cv[i] = maxi;   
    }
}

int main()
{
    int rowVector[rows];
    int colVector[cols];
    int a[rows][cols];

    cout << "Fill Array_1. " << endl;
    getData(a, rows);

    cout << "Array_1." << "\n\n";
    printData(a, rows); cout << endl;

    maxValuesR(a, rowVector, rows);
    print_single(rowVector, rows);

    cout << "\n\n";

    maxValuesC(a, colVector, rows);
    print_single(colVector, rows);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so what compilation errors do you get?

Comment: It's hard to understand an error you cannot see.

Comment: what are your errors? why don't you use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of the C-like arrays? why do you use the same name for constants and local variables? it's hard to follow.

Comment: First, it would help to see all of the code, including the includes and and `using namespace` lines.  Second, post the errors you're seeing.

Comment: Using `using namespace std;` is almost invariably a bad idea.

Comment: i've comment out the error. Please check it out .
The error is in this function
void maxValuesC(int a[][cols], int cv[], int row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify the compile errors:

- You forgot the include (or didn't write it here?) `#include <iostream>`
- You didn't specify the namespace for `cin`, `cout` and `endl` (they are in `std` namespace)
- You had a superfluous "[" in the statement `a[j][[i]`, by all likelihood you wanted to write `a[j][i]`

The compiling code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

const int rows = 2;     // Declared As Global Variable
const int cols = 3; // Declared As Global Variable

void getData(int arr[][cols], int rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter Element: ";
            std::cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

}

void printData(int a[][cols], int rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            std::cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void print_single(int a[], int row)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i] << "\t";
    }
}

void maxValuesR(int a[][cols], int rv[], int row)
{   int foxi;
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        foxi = a[i][0];
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {

                if(foxi < a[i][j])
                {
                    foxi = a[i][j];
                }
            }
            rv[i] = foxi;
    }
}

void maxValuesC(int a[][cols], int cv[], int row)
{
    int maxi;
    for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        maxi = a[0][i];
            for(int j = 0; j < row; j++)
            {

                if(maxi > a[j][i])
                {
                    maxi = a[j][i];
                }
            }
            cv[i] = maxi;   
    }
}

int main()
{
    int rowVector[rows];
    int colVector[cols];
    int a[rows][cols];

    std::cout << "Fill Array_1. " << std::endl;
    getData(a, rows);

    std::cout << "Array_1." << "\n\n";
    printData(a, rows);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    maxValuesR(a, rowVector, rows);
    print_single(rowVector, rows);

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    maxValuesC(a, colVector, rows);
    print_single(colVector, rows);

    return 0;
}
```

Can't tell whether it produces the output you want, though, because you didn't specify any example input (let alone the corresponding expected output)...

Comment: And what is the question now? Check my 3rd point - seems you didn't really read my answer? Also see the code I posted - **the full code I give in my answer above compiles**! I'd recommend to try it out? and then if it doesn't work as expected, create a new question and include: **the input you give to the program, the output you get, and the output you would have expected**